# Android calling .net webservice Ksoap2

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am calling a .NET webservice using ksoap2 in android and i get a response someting like this 
`anyType{NewDataSet=anyType{string=77777};` how can i parse this. please help!

Comment: is it a ksoap response or json response ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a multidimensional array of properties, it goes like :

```
anyType //property 0 
{
  NewDataSet=anyType // property 0 [0]
   {
     string=77777;
   }
};
```

you can parse it manually (this is java code):

```
SoapObject yourResponseObject = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
SoapObject array = (SoapObject) yourResponseObject .getProperty(0);// this is -->anyType //property 0           

SoapObject NewDataSetArray= (SoapObject)array .getProperty(0);// this is--> // property 0 [0]   
//PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();

//NewDataSetArray.getPropertyInfo(0, propertyInfo);

String temp = null;
//if(propertyInfo.name.equalsIgnoreCase("NewDataset"))
//{
    temp = NewDataSetArray.getProperty(0).toString();// this is 77777
//}
```

i did not test it, but it should work and i guess you got the point.

Comment: when i am passing NewDataSet  in `propertyInfo.name.equalsIgnoreCase("NewDataset")` i get null ; so i printed `propertyInfo.name` and i got `Android_UserLocation` and user Android_UserLocation instead of NewDataSet  , but this also gives me anyType

Comment: @TusharAgarwal i commented out some parts, try outputing temp, what do you get?

Comment: thankx but this gives me the same ..anyways i have got the solution ,iteratng it 3 times and then getting the property by name itself.