# Android Ksoap get a list array of class from webservice

Tags: java, android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

i am developing an android application to get  a list of class from wevservice

the method of webservice is like `List<mytable> GetAllmytableData();` But i cant cast that data in my mytable class. i create a mytable class as http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html this link suggested.
also applied **kvm serialization** in myclass to cast data. but always getting getting  `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject`  error.

Data i getting in soapenvelope is like

```
anyType{DisplayName=a; Email=hi@y.com; FirstName=a; LastChangedDate=2/5/2012 11:24:38 PM; LastName=a; ObserverID=1; UserID=1; }
anyType{DisplayName=b; Email=hi@y.com; FirstName=b; LastChangedDate=2/5/2012 11:25:52 PM; LastName=b; ObserverID=1; UserID=2; }
 anyType{DisplayName=c; Email=hi@y.com; FirstName=c; LastChangedDate=2/6/2012 9:10:44 AM; LastName=c; ObserverID=3; UserID=3; }
```

how i can parse and put in my "mytable" class's object array,

any suggestion on link plz provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kishor, this is a multi dimensional array take the first one:

```
anyType//property 0 
{
 DisplayName=a; // property 0 [0]
 Email=hi@y.com; // property 0 [1]
 FirstName=a; // property 0 [2]
 LastChangedDate=2/5/2012 11:24:38 PM; //etc...
 LastName=a; 
 ObserverID=1;
 UserID=1; 
}
```

you can get each property manually like that:

```
SoapObject yourResponseObject = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
SoapObject array = (SoapObject) yourResponseObject .getProperty(0);// this is -->anyType //property 0           

SoapObject DisplayName= (SoapObject)array .getProperty(0);// this is--> //   property 0 [0]  ;
SoapObject Email= (SoapObject)array .getProperty(1);// this is--> //   property 0 [1]  ;
```

etc...
also if you want check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068161/android-calling-net-webservice-ksoap2/9074239#9074239)

Answer (score 1):

Try use an array instead of a List.