# Passing complex type to KSOAP Android Library

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Newbie here in Android and KSOAP2.  I am trying to call a soap based web service but I am having difficulty passing the
complex object in calling it.

My webservice requires the following complex input object.
This schema represents my input and output messages.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/ViewCustDetails" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="ViewCustDetails">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="inputs" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="option" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xsd:element name="variant" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" default="ACCT_ID"/>
                    <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="results" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="customerId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xsd:element name="customerName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xsd:element name="custClass" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

When requesting or calling the web service I need to populate the "inputs" element **only**.
The "results" element **can be neglected** during outgoing call.

When the webservice returns, the "results" element are populated with what you have assigned and the  elements are 
properly populated with the value.

I am just having difficulty on how to send the complex object in KSOAP 2 and retrieve the corresponding returned data.
Most of the examples that I have found so far contains only simple objects and the schema is simple so I am struggling on how
to solve this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: check my answers [here][1],[here][2],[here][3],[here][4].

Let me know if you need further help
[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355707/how-to-create-soap-request-via-ksoap2/9369810#9369810
[2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023442/android-wsdl-web-service-ksoap2/9042267#9042267
[3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968620/android-soapfault-error/9042499#9042499
[4]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068161/android-calling-net-webservice-ksoap2/9074239#9074239

Comment: check my code here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846149/passing-objects-to-wcf-soap-service-from-android-using-ksoap2-it-sends-and-rece/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Adding an array of complex objects to the request](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#Adding_an_array_of_complex_objects_to_the_request)